# Width of root - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've got a problem with my kivy program... Especially with the width of my root, it's more less than the width of the window...

Like this :

[here](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Sq32eDiBdEQ/VLVlqXaB5LI/AAAAAAAAAYg/ydoS3gxXMaU/s1600/example.png)

I don't understand...

Here my code:

First python file :

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Config.set('graphics','width','450')
Config.set('graphics','height','800')

class Saisi(Widget):
    pass

class Jeu(Widget):
    pass

class WorDown(App):
    def build(self):
        return Jeu()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorDown().run()
```

And my kivy file:

```
<Saisi>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: root.width , 50 ← I think, this is it...

<Jeu>:
    Saisi:
        y: root.height / 2
```

Someone can help me ? I just want to "resize" the "root width", because all my elements have a max width like this...

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Jeu>:
    Saisi:
        y: root.height / 2
```

Jeu is a widget and not a special layout type, so it doesn't impose any position or size on its children, therefore the Saisi instance has the default position of (0, 0) and size of (100, 100).

Make Jeu inherit from e.g. BoxLayout (recommended), or alternatively manually set the Saisi pos/size to match that of the Jeu in the above rule.

Comment: `from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout` and `class Jeu(BoxLayout):`